# Помогите правильно оформить код. Переменная в блоке try не годится, если выполнился catch

Tags: java

`unixTimeDate` мне приходится хоть как нибудь инициализировать заранее, потому что в блоке `try` может быть исключение. Во первых , если исключение выпало , то дальнейшее выполнение кода бессмысленно, как его правильно прервать? верно ли написать в блоке `catch return`? Это ведь осуществит выход из метода? 
 Ну и основной  вопрос, в том как красиво оформить этот код. Как видите, часть кода где я использую этот `unixTimeDate` в не блока `try` я не могу перенести в блок `try` потому, что тогда мне придется инициализировать вне блока `try` `Cursor`, что тоже не является удобным вариантом.  Может написанный мною вариант является уже оптимальным?

```
 String getAnswer(String strDate, String currency) {
            long unixTimeDate = 1;
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
                format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date date = format.parse(strDate);
                unixTimeDate = date.getTime();

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Cursor c = exchangeRatesDatabase.query("ExchangeRatesTable",
                    new String[]{"json"},
                    "date = ?",
                    new String[]{Long.toString(unixTimeDate)},
                    null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int idColJson = c.getColumnIndex("json");
                String answer = c.getString(idColJson);
                c.close(); 
                return answer;
            }
            return "0";
        }
```

Кстати попробовал в блоке catch написать return и это позволяет вообще не инициализировать, а просто объявить переменную `unixTimeDate`. Наверно это и есть самый правильный вариант..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> если исключение выпало , то дальнейшее выполнение кода бессмысленно,
> как его правильно прервать?

- Можно не ловить исключение в блоке, а позволить вылететь из функции, тогда в том месте, где вылетело исключение функция прервется.
- Или выйти из функции через оператор `return`. Например: `return null`

> верно ли написать в блоке catch return? Это ведь осуществит выход из метода?

Верно.

Да.

---

Чтобы не ловить исключение, нужно в описании функции в `throws` указать исключения, которые могут вылететь:

```
String getAnswer(String strDate, String currency) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = format.parse(strDate);
    long unixTimeDate = date.getTime();

    Cursor c = exchangeRatesDatabase.query(
        "ExchangeRatesTable",
        new String[]{"json"},
        "date = ?",
        new String[]{Long.toString(unixTimeDate)},
        null, null, null
    );
    
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColJson = c.getColumnIndex("json");
        String answer = c.getString(idColJson);
        c.close();
        
        return answer;
    }
    
    return "0";
}
```

---

Вариант попроще:

```
String getAnswer(String strDate, String currency) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
        format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = format.parse(strDate);
        long unixTimeDate = date.getTime();

        Cursor c = exchangeRatesDatabase.query(
            "ExchangeRatesTable",
            new String[]{"json"},
            "date = ?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(unixTimeDate)},
            null, null, null
        );

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int idColJson = c.getColumnIndex("json");
            String answer = c.getString(idColJson);
            c.close();

            return answer;
        }
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }
    
    // Если что-то пошло не так, вернем дефолтное значение
    return "0";
}
```

Comment: А как мне не ловить исключение? Компилятор заставляет его ловить

Comment: gil9red, Йооу. круто. я как раз разбирал тему исключений и непонятым оставался trows .  Ну хорошо, а вылетит он из метода с чем? У меня там код ожидает, что этот метод мне вернет строку. В таком случае для меня правильно вернуть return "0" , как я и задумал.

Comment: вылетит то исключение, тогда код вокруг `getAnswer` нужно обернуть в try/catch. Либо, весь блок внутри функции описать в try { ... }  catch (Exception e) { // ignore }, а после вызвать `return "0"`. Т.е. если все хорошо, сработает внутренний return, при любом исключении, наследуемом от Exception, выдадим стандартное значение

Comment: Спасибо. я с этим же кодом связанный еще один вопрос создам, буду рад если заглянете.